# CMake error for Raspberry PI Pico while using cmake command

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to make the https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master
pico examples in ubuntu while running cmake, I get following error, when I comment the that line it compiles but not generating output files.

`CMake Error at serial/CMakeLists.txt:9 (pico_add_extra_outputs): Unknown CMake command "pico_add_extra_outputs".`

I tried commenting the line pico_add_extra_outputs(hello_serial) and  example_auto_set_url(hello_serial) then it compiles but not getting the output files for pico.

`add_executable(hello_serial
hello_serial.c
)

## pull in common dependencies

target_link_libraries(hello_serial pico_stdlib)

## create map/bin/hex/uf2 file etc.

pico_add_extra_outputs(hello_serial)

## add url via pico_set_program_url

example_auto_set_url(hello_serial)`